# imagemagick square to circle crop and merge as icon

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick via PHP and would like to extend on this resource:

http://joedesigns.com/v22/?page=scripts_widgets&id=15

```
<?php

function sqThm($src,$dest,$size=75){

            $squareSize = 70;

            list($w,$h) = getimagesize($src);

            if($w > $h){
               exec("convert ".$src." -resize x".$size." -quality 100 ".$dest);
            }else{
               exec("convert ".$src." -resize ".$size." -quality 100 ".$dest);
            }

            exec("convert ".$dest." -gravity Center -crop ".$size."x".$size."+0+0 ".$dest);

}

if(!$_GET[imgtosquare]){

   print "
   <p>Click on the image you want to conver to a square.</p>
   <p><a href='index.php?imgtosquare=1'><img src='gfx/1.jpg' border='0'></a></p>
   <p><a href='index.php?imgtosquare=2'><img src='gfx/2.jpg' border='0'></a></p>
   ";

}else{

   if($_GET[imgtosquare] != '1' && $_GET[imgtosquare] != '2'){ exit; }

   sqThm("gfx/".$_GET[imgtosquare].".jpg","gfx/".$_GET[imgtosquare]."_squared.jpg");

   print "
   <p>Here is your squared image.</p>
   <p><img src='gfx/".$_GET[imgtosquare]."_squared.jpg' border='0'></p>
   ";

}

?>
```

...which takes an image and produces a flickr style squared image that I want to still save but also further process to take this:

[image: icon base]

and produce this as an additional saved file:

[image: end result]

(Note the checkered areas are transparent)

How would I modify the script to do this?  Also, please note that I expect a large volume of these images to be processed, so execution efficiency is also important.  Finally - the format for all resulting images will be PNG, although input file may be JPG.

Answer (score 1):

The [examples book](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) has every imaginable example on ImageMagick usage. Check them out.

The [Masks](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#masks) chapter should help achieving your goal, although it may require you to edit your pink original image further.